# How to show data from 3 different table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7

I want show data when a user click on order icon and it show what product he has order in order detail page.

I have 3 tables like :

-User : id, name, email, phone_no

-Product : id, id_category, name, price, stock, image, descpition

-Order : id, id_user(1 to many : user), id_product(1 to many : product), date, price, total_order, total_price

I already write `$orderdetail = order::(id_user',auth()->id())->get();` in ordercontroller and I recognize that it show data from **user** and **order** table only, I have no idea what to do.

Please help me

In **orderdetail.blade.php**

```
<?php $no=1 ?> 

@foreach ($orderdetail as $order)
{{$no++}}
{{$order->id}}
{{$order->data}}
{{$order->id_product->name}}
{{$order->price}}
{{$order->total_order}}
{{$order->total_price}}
```

If I write `{{$order->id_product->name}}` the result say **the result says Trying to get property 'name' of non object**

Answer (score -1):

That's what relationships are for:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction

You need more table and correct relations: `OrderProductS`,  `ProductCategories`

```
Tables (should be plural):

-Users (id, name, email, phone_no)
-Products (id, name, price, stock, description)

-Categories (id, name)
-ProductCategories(id, product_id, category_id)

-Orders (id, user_id, date, total_order, total_price)
-OrderProducts (id, order_id, product_id)

Models:
   [Relations]
-User
   [order, one to many]
-Product
   [category, many to many]
   [orderProducts, many to one]
-Category
   [product, many to many]
-ProductCategory
   [product, many to many]
-Order
   [user, many to many]
   [orderProducts, one to many]
-OrderProducts
   [product, one to many]
   [order, many to one]


$user_orders = auth()->orders->getOrdersById($order_id);
$order = $user_orders[0]; //or $user_orders->first();
    
$order_details = [
    'total_order' => $order->total_order,
    'total_price' => $order->total_price,
    'products'    => $order->orderProducts,
]

return view('some-page', $order_details);
```

In blade

```
{{ $total_order}}
{{ $total_price}}

@foreach ($products as $product)
    {{ $product->id }}
    {{ $product->price }}
    {{ $product->stock }}
    {{ $product->... }}
@endforach
```

Comment: The problem is not in relationship, I do not know how to write the code in that put order, product and user in to $orderdetail in orderdetailcontroller

Comment: As I told, you need to prepare correct relation, than you can place it to array or collection, and forward to view